# using lucene fuzzy search and synonyms with Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I want to be able to handle fuzzy search, as well as synonyms at the same time.
I tried it in a several ways, but I cannot get it working.

I have these values in my index:

```
white
black
light
dark
```

and this synonym rules:

```
white,light
black,dark
```

If I perform the query `queryType=full&search=light` or `queryType=full&search=white`, it always returns both values, light and white.
So synonyms are working.

If I perform the query `queryType=full&search=light~1`, then only light will be returned. But where is white?

Is the combination of fuzzy search and synonyms not possible yet, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synonym expansions do not apply to wildcard search terms; prefix, fuzzy, and regex terms aren't expanded.

If you need to do a single query that applies synonym expansion and wildcard, regex, or fuzzy searches, you can combine the queries using the *OR* syntax.

For example, to combine synonyms with fuzzy search you would need to have query like this:

```
search=light~1|light
```

or

```
queryType=full&search=light OR light~1
```

if you're using Lucene query syntax

Comment: I understand. But unfortunately when I try `queryType=full&search=light~1|light` it returns `light` but no synonyms. If I try `queryType=full&search=light|light~1` it returns nothing. Any Ideas?

Comment: I got it. I have to use *OR*. `queryType=full&search=light OR light~1` is working. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, yes. I was providing simple syntax example not the full